# How to measure MQTT and Kafka latency?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, mqtt, latency

as part of my final year project at the uni i have to simulate a fog-cloud environment and measure the latencies. I use a DHT11 temperature sensor to measure temperature and humidity. I use MQTT to simulate my fog node and Apache Kafka to simulate my cloud node. I have a Mosquitto MQTT broker that is running locally and i have an instance of Apache Kafka running in the cloud (Microsoft Azure). I have a python client (paho-mqtt and pykafka based) that takes the data from the DHT11 sensor and forwards it to the MQTT and from there on the data is forwarded to Apache Kafka running in the cloud. Everything is working fine but i have no idea how to measure the latency. The idea is to measure the time it takes for the data to reach the respective MQTT and Kafka topics. Does anyone have any idea how this would work or has done a similar project in the past? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Install Jaeger/Zipkin server for distributed tracing and write service traces to it from your Python clients

Comment: hey man, thank you for your suggestion. I have never heard of these tracing systems. Is it hard to set them up and do the measurements? Do you have any good tutorials on how to set them up? The thing is, i dont have much time and thats why it should be something that is not too hard or takes too much time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: They're no harder to setup than Kafka or anything else, after reading their documentation

Comment: what do you think about simple timestamps?